# how to check items under div in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I need to check items in div having below xpath.

xpath of items is like

Item 1:- `//*[@id='huc-last-upsell-rows']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a/img`

Item 2:- `//*[@id='huc-last-upsell-rows']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/a/img`

Item 3:- `//*[@id='huc-last-upsell-rows']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/a/img`

Item 4:- `//*[@id='huc-last-upsell-rows']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/a/img`

How can I check it? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean with 'check' ? You want to obtain whether they are there ? You want to retrieve those elements from the dom or you want to mark them in some way ?

Comment: Yes i want to check item is present if yes then i want to click on it. then same loop for remaining items.

Comment: Please provide sample of html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++){
    String expression = "//*[@id='huc-last-upsell-rows']/div[1]/div[2]/div["+ i+"]/div/div/a/img";
    Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath(expression)).size() > 0;
    if(isPresent){
       // click or do other action
    }
}
```

Comment: or use the already present methods of WebElement for that like `isDisplayed()` or `isPresent()`

Comment: @karna: i need to know how can i loop elements changing xpath in div [ ].

Comment: @Dude `isDisplayed` checks if element is displayed or not, it dont check for existence. Element might exist but can be hidden.  Now aware of `isPresent` method in Java webdrive api, can you add something about it?

Comment: @Karna im sorry i got it confused, it is not officially in the WebElement api. i did implement this function myself. and it looks like yours :D

Comment: @Dude I also did similar implementation, was wondering if new version have it.

Comment: @karna i will tell you my scenario for better understanding, 1st i need to list out how many items are present on web page. In HTML they not used list for these item list developer use div for each item.

Comment: @Santosh Still its not clear, please update question with details.